# Как удалить все файлы из папки с помощью PHP?

Tags: php, файлы

У меня большое количество посетителей в день и создаётся до 50 тысяч сессий в день. Пишу скрипт, чтобы когда число сессий в папке mod-tmp превысит 20 тысяч, сервер удалял бы из неё все файлы и перезагружался. Помогите, пожалуйста, как с помощью PHP удалить **все** файлы из 1 папки?

Comment: Вроде как нельзя удалить сразу все. Можно получить список и удалить в цикле, но это долго.
Можно попробовать через exec запускать внешнюю программу.
Или вообще написать демона который будет работать выше чем пхп и быстрее

Comment: Довольно интересный я бы сказал не вопрос а ситуация. Копайте в торону **cron php**

Comment: > чтобы когда число сессий в папке mod-tmp привышало 20 тысяч сервер удалял из неё все файлы и перезагружался

Простите, но это форменный кошмар, других слов я просто не нахожу. 

Во-первых, PHP сам чистит протухшие сессии, если не менялись настройки [`session.gc-*`](http://php.net/session.configuration#ini.session.gc-probability)

А во-вторых, вас не волнует, что пользователей будет постоянно выкидывать с сайта, не говоря уже о неработоспособности сайта во время перезагрузки?

Answer (score 4):

Вот самый быстрый и лёгкий способ:

```
function clear() {
    if (file_exists('/cache/')) {
        foreach (glob('/cache/*') as $file) {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }
}
```

Дальше вызываете где и когда нужно. К примеру, если это Wordpress, вешаете `add_action('save_post','clear')`.

Answer (score 3):

Грубый подход, очень грубый:

```
$baseDir = "./";
exec("rm -f " .$baseDir . "/dir/*");
```

Это сработает только в Linux. Еще раз скажу, подход очень грубый и лучше такого не использовать **НИКОГДА**.

Answer (score 3):

Удалить средствами `php` сразу все не получится. Только в цикле. Возможно следует посмотреть в сторону демонов, как сказал @Inart.
Код для пхп:

```
function cleanDir($dir) {
    $files = glob($dir."/*");
    $c = count($files);
    if (count($files) > 0) {
        foreach ($files as $file) {      
            if (file_exists($file)) {
            unlink($file);
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно, всё намного проще. ISPManager криво меняет конфиг php отключая сборщик мусора сессий.

Открывайте конфиг php. По-дефолту `/etc/php.d/apache/php.ini`

Меняйте параметр `session.gc_probability=0` в значение `1`

Перезапускаете аппач `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Всё, сборка мусора снова — дело php.

Answer (score 0):

А попробуйте лучше удалять не все сразу, а постепенно. То есть PHP-скрипт каждого пользователя, который зашел к вам на сайт, будет удалять, например, по 1000 файлов, пока их не останется вовсе.
Это сделать не сложно. Достаточно одного XML-Файла ( БД здесь не обязательно использовать) с двумя записями - сколько осталось и вторая - надо ли производить удаление.

Answer (score 0):

```
array_map('unlink', glob('./cache/*'));
```

Answer (score -1):

У меня вот таким скриптом все удалило... подчистую... вместе с сайтом...

```
if ($objs = glob($dir."/*")) {
    echo $objs;
    foreach($objs as $obj) {
        if(is_dir($obj)){
            
        }else{
            unlink($obj);
        }
    }
}
rmdir($dir);
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?